# Upgrading IdentityServer4 to Core 3.1 - tokens are suddenly not signed correctly?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

We encountered an error while upgrading IdentityServer4 (2.5.3 - 3.1.0) to Core 3.1 (from 2.2). Suddenly tokens that are issued doesn't have the correct signature. We haven't changed the signing algorithm; still using the same .PFX-certificate between versions.

```
var idSrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(opts =>
            {
                opts.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                if (_env.IsProduction())
                {
                    opts.PublicOrigin = Configuration["Globals:IdentityURL"];
                }
            }).AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Configuration["Cert:Path"], Configuration["Cert:Password"]));
```

When using the OWIN middleware "UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication" for an older API it fails if `ValidationMode` is `Local` but not if it's validating directly against the IdentityServer (with `ValidationMode` `ValidationEndpoint`). The API will only return "Unauthorized" but works with the older token (same certificate signing them!)

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = AppSettings.Authority,
                ClientId = AppSettings.ApiName,
                ClientSecret = AppSettings.ApiSecret,
                EnableValidationResultCache = false,
                ValidationMode = IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.ValidationMode.Local
            });
```

Looking at the token issued between versions there's a glaring difference:

Old (removed payload):

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZCMTM4RUIzMUE4OUExQTdEQTdCNkRGNzMwOTRGMzIzREJFNzhCNjYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJheE9Pc3hxSm9hZmFlMjMzTUpUekk5dm5pMlkifQ.U3unxhW6act8fQLCLAYBJAZ-lIMiKaghVEUdA3b7iM0mI0UqGmYgYw05SvVXTAT8ZNQPuq0D-97d0Z6VVBC2wH7VAl0daF6sYJyuSUEtDiBPttNQ9MsGBNjcN1HABZ0nv-z_lgG2Z9sgp4blCvc7N8xOsja-kuk6m06I7iOfS7O_YKPtTAXA10OCzdtiJbhYijeTFsBJaWf5-J3XJCtqpp-MGXCboE0gQIlvysKz5_CRaaKYptczw-cTX3sgRIhfWn2VxVujhH7JKeSJan52X-fQ4T47PWuVcWNOrcWheeLAbVDQU1U9DiLVVua3BasnIku5Rx4XcLnqCaokCiWZhg
```

With the following token header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "6B138EB31A89A1A7DA7B6DF73094F323DBE78B66",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "axOOsxqJoafae233MJTzI9vni2Y"
}
```

New:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZCMTM4RUIzMUE4OUExQTdEQTdCNkRGNzMwOTRGMzIzREJFNzhCNjYiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QiLCJ4NXQiOiJheE9Pc3hxSm9hZmFlMjMzTUpUekk5dm5pMlkifQ.RmKHRk44c6Ele-VbB8lhNsmmcvKFludaWypuBzQzYqR7AEIuLXAuZ-N4I9ooVvQLHisBJT4qA4epEK9xdtf0ELpcvfEe3Yc2dkJnKp_rjJSRuhqyNHD0hPAoxqVSWHhfaLxLiL7_17mklqLDEqwdXANnA2YCO-Q-9wqGALZorywHYucr0X9m2hYm1oVgXPitG_TAqysYVNnLCHVGZRNE7Xmug0XhkJXzQ8RpZuSHlDHFlT2cgb7psEb4NUfA8v5-q-LyqfPDk4xJZX2ia53SoPpiJbByFgscYF4xk54SkkcB9EOxCCsR-IYHJAmyYkhGRpBVWY5xU_9qb2ioIwkzZg
```

With the following header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "6B138EB31A89A1A7DA7B6DF73094F323DBE78B66",
  "typ": "at+jwt",
  "x5t": "axOOsxqJoafae233MJTzI9vni2Y"
}
```

I'm guessing the issue is that `"typ"` from the new token is `"at+jwt"`? What does that mean? I've looked at IdentityServers releases, Github issues, googled, searched stackoverflow but no one seems to have noticed the mysterious new `"at+jwt"` `"typ"`.

Could that be causing the issue? How can I instruct my new version to issue a standard JWT? And what is this strange `at+jwt`?

Comment: This is called [explicit typing](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/09/13/use-explicit-typing-for-your-jwts/). You can disable this behaviour by overriding the value using [IdentityServer Options](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/docs/reference/options.rst#identityserver-options).

Comment: Thanks! Seems to have solved the issue

Comment: In addition, just found this [issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3705).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ruard van Elburg in the comments for linking to explicit typed tokens.

Changing the default "at+jwt" to just "jwt" solved the issue:

```
var idSrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(opts =>
            {
                opts.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                opts.AccessTokenJwtType = "jwt";
                if (_env.IsProduction())
                {
                    opts.PublicOrigin = Configuration["Globals:IdentityURL"];
                }
            });
```

I'm guessing the underlying issue is with the package `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` we're using in that API not being able to recognize at+jwt. We're using that so that we can potentielly support reference tokens.

We also can't upgrade this API to ASP Core and use the newer `IdentityServerAuthenticationExtensions` from Microsoft due to some depedencies from third parties we need to support. That package does seem to be able to handle `at+jwt` just fine.

EDIT:

Still didn't work. Had a look at the Github issue that Ruard linked to.

Turns out I also had to turn on EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim so not it looks like this:

```
var idSrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(opts =>
            {
                opts.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                opts.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                opts.AccessTokenJwtType = "JWT";
                opts.EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim = true;
                if (_env.IsProduction())
                {
                    opts.PublicOrigin = Configuration["Globals:IdentityURL"];
                }
            })
```

Comment: Actually, I suspect it's one level deeper. The AccessTokenValidation package calls [JwtFormat](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/master/source/AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L197) without specifying the type. JwtFormat then sets the [AuthenticationType parameter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt/JwtFormat.cs#L110) for validation: `_validationParameters.AuthenticationType = "JWT";`.

Comment: It appears that didn't solve it. I forgot to change the ValidationMode to "Local" or "Both" and immediately we're getting "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Tried to change the signing keys, also didn't work.

Comment: In my case, this solution worked! Thank you very much! Can this be flagged as an answer somehow?

Comment: Now IdentityServer4 changes to EmitStaticAudienceClaim instead of EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim.